# no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Function <A, B> conforms to Function <A, C> where B is interface implemented by C

Tags: java, function, generics, interface

I am getting the error

```
Required type: Function<A, B>
Provided: Function<A,C<D>>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Function<A, C<D>> conforms to Function<A, B>
```

Now B is an interface defined like

```
public interface B <U extends X, V extends Y> {}
```

C implements the interface B like

```
public abstract class C <T extends Y> implements B <X, T>
```

Now if I write something as

```
B data = getBean(SomeFactory.class);
```

where `getBean(SomeFactory.class)` gives an instance of `C<D>`
then this statement is valid as `C implements B`.
But if I write

```
Function<A,B> supplier = getBean(SomeSupplierFactory.class);
```

where `getBean(SomeSupplierFactory.class)` gives an instance of `Function<A, C<D>>` it throws the above error i.e.

```
Required type: Function<A, B>
Provided: Function<A,C<D>>
no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that Function<A, C<D>> conforms to Function<A, B>
```

even though `C` is an implementation of `B`

Please let me know what am I missing and how to make the above work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why is `B` a `Function` at all? According to what you’ve posted before, it is not. Or perhaps, you should explain, how the arguments `SomeFactory.class` or `SomeSupplierFactory.class` affect what the method `getBean` returns. Further, there was no mentioning of `A` before.

Comment: `B` has type parameters, so you should be writing `B<This, That> data = getBean(SomeFactory.class);` instead of using `B` without type arguments. And also `Function<A,B<This, That>> supplier = ...;`

Comment: @Holger B is not a function.. Later we want to change the implementation which returns a function like
`aObject -> bObject` i.e. return type will be `Function<A,B>`. Why I have not mentioned A is because its just a constant behavior which does not have impact on this question.

Comment: B has type parameter but we cannot use it as this is a generic behavior.
Having said that the issue is not there and everything works as expected even without the params
`B data = objectOfC` works. Basically `getBean(SomeFactory.class)` is essentially `objectOfC`

Comment: So your question is why, e.g. a `Function<T,String>` is not a `Function<T,Object>` and all remaining stuff in your question is irrelevant. The answer is, there are no covariant “out type parameters” in Java, so the use site has to declare the variance, e.g. `Function<A, ? extends B> supplier = …`. To avoid the need for such declarations, methods receiving a function should follow the [PECS rule](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2711488) and every reasonable library follows this pattern, so you can simply keep `Function<A, C<D>>` and pass it to any method expecting `Function<A, ? extends B>`